# Android background app

Tags: android, audio-streaming

Is it possible for an android app running in the background to access the sound being produced by a media player (to be used for recording to another file, streaming etc)? Will the app read from the sound port? How will this work if it is possible? Any existing apps?

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Or more precisely: on an unmodified Android device there is no audio loop back or pass through functionality.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html lists all the audio sources available to the MediaRecorder and AudioRecorder classes.

Now, if you are willing to write a device driver and have the capacity to root the target device and load your driver on it you could possibly implement a loop back driver, a pass through driver or (much more interesting) an alternative audio output device that would perform your streaming/recording and then forward to the regular audio output.

Comment: Well, perhaps: if you dig around in http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=tree you can find the IMediaPlayerService interface which the platform media player uses. This gives a bunch of info about what's currently playing and crucially there is a "getPath()" method. Not quite sure what it would return if you're playing a stream, but you may get some mileage out of it.

Answer (score 0):

To caputre a Sound-Output form the Android Device, you can use the MediaRecorder-class, like shown in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#capture).

But recording a Sound-File, which already exists (on the SDcard ore something) doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Thanks. Can we save the output to memory and stream it? or stream the output dirrectly?

Comment: I don't know any standard functionality which aloes you o stream music to another device with Android. Maybe there is a Library to that, but I don't know any.